# Join on two dis-similar column

Tags: sql, database, string, inner-join

I need to join one column of a table to a column of another table.

Now these two column consists the geographic region data. But the issue is the column dont have exactly same strings od data.

For ex. `Latin America` in one column and `LATM` in another.

The data is table if had been same string would be the simplest joins but these two mean the same but then are different strings . What do I use to accomplish my task.

I need to do is

```
Select * from Table1 Inner Join Table2 on table1.region = table2.region
```

Comment: You need a mapping table.  A table that has one column as `Latin America` and the other `LATM`.  Then join through that table.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a mapping table which maps every possible region in Table1.region to every possible region in Table2

for example your Mapping table be like.

```
MappingTable
--------------------------
Region1       |  Region 2
--------------------------
Latin America |  LATM     
Europe        |  EUR
.....
```

The you can create a join like

```
Select * 
from 
    Table1 
inner join 
    MappingTable 
on
    Table1.region = MappingTable.Region1
inner join
    Table2
on
    MappingTable.Region2 = Table2.region
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make another table which contains information of TWO table Joining like **'Latin America'** = **'LATM'** and then have to use this table in join.